# Asp mvc 5 Entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

How to sum up the values of the fields in a separate column in the lines?

```
public class Ball    
{    
    public int BallId { get; set; }
    public int Ball1 { get; set; }
    public int Ball2 { get; set; }
    public int Ball3 { get; set; }

    public int Summa {
        get {return Ball1 + Ball2;}
        private set { }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Put some code you are using to display the columns.

Comment: You can do it by your controller/Action.Pls, show us your controller

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Computed Entity Framework does not allow the rows table?

Answer (score 0):

create a separate partial call and define your property.

```
public partial class Ball    
{        

    public int Summa {
        get {return Ball1 + Ball2;}
        private set { }
    }
```

Comment: Create a custom public partial class called Ball?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: when you create a model using Entity Framework it actually create classes against your tables so what you have to do is create a partial class of your required table  add some properties you want , the reason to add partial class is ever time you update your EF model it regenerate the code from database so any modification in existing class will be vanished there for you have to create your own file with partial class.  feel free if you need more help